# Sygic Custom URL not working for iOS

Tags: ios, custom-url, sygic

I am using iOS [custom URL scheme](https://www.sygic.com/developers/professional-navigation-sdk/ios/custom-url) and i want to create a route in sygic app. As mentioned on their documentation to load a json (.sif) itinerary, I am using their custom URL scheme

> com.sygic.aura://route%7Cmyitinerary.sif

to load my .sif file.

```html
{
 "name": "test",
 "version": "2.2",
 "directives": {
  "allowItineraryEdit": true
 },
 "routeParts": [{
   "properties": {
    "routeMappingType": "none",
    "precomputed": false,
    "map": "NT:2017.09"
   },
   "waypointFrom": {
    "lon": -315442,
    "lat": 5149939,
    "lonNavi": -315442,
    "latNavi": 5149939,
    "type": "start",
    "waypointId": -1,
    "hitRadius": 50,
    "hitSpeed": 50,
    "caption": "Barons Court Road 21/34, Cardiff, Penylan",
    "realtimeStatus": {
     "status": "visited",
     "estimatedTimeArrival": "2018-04-17T13:08:15Z",
     "timeRemaining": 0,
     "distanceRemaining": 0,
     "edited": false
    }
   },
   "waypointTo": {
    "lon": -312245,
    "lat": 5151827,
    "lonNavi": -312245,
    "latNavi": 5151827,
    "type": "via",
    "waypointId": -1,
    "hitRadius": 50,
    "hitSpeed": 50,
    "caption": "Llanrumney Avenue 193/218, Cardiff, Llanrumney",
    "realtimeStatus": {
     "status": "unvisited",
     "estimatedTimeArrival": "2018-04-17T13:19:34Z",
     "timeRemaining": 679,
     "distanceRemaining": 4214,
     "edited": false
    }
   }
  }, {
   "properties": {
    "routeMappingType": "none",
    "precomputed": false,
    "map": "NT:2017.09"
   },
   "waypointFrom": {
    "lon": -312245,
    "lat": 5151827,
    "lonNavi": -312245,
    "latNavi": 5151827,
    "type": "via",
    "waypointId": -1,
    "hitRadius": 50,
    "hitSpeed": 50,
    "caption": "Llanrumney Avenue 193/218, Cardiff, Llanrumney",
    "realtimeStatus": {
     "status": "unvisited",
     "estimatedTimeArrival": "2018-04-17T13:19:34Z",
     "timeRemaining": 679,
     "distanceRemaining": 4214,
     "edited": false
    }
   },
   "waypointTo": {
    "lon": -314670,
    "lat": 5152479,
    "lonNavi": -314670,
    "latNavi": 5152479,
    "type": "finish",
    "waypointId": -1,
    "hitRadius": 50,
    "hitSpeed": 50,
    "caption": "Pentwyn, United Kingdom",
    "realtimeStatus": {
     "status": "unvisited",
     "estimatedTimeArrival": "2018-04-17T13:29:51Z",
     "timeRemaining": 1296,
     "distanceRemaining": 10859,
     "edited": false
    }
   }
  }]
}
```

The app is triggered and its opened. But i am getting an wierd message as in the screenshot.

Can anyone help me why i am getting this issue please ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the documentation, because this custom url is not working for iOS just for Android application, due to file access limitation on iOS. The only workaround is to use com.sygic.aura://route_download | url (sif or json) and upload this itinerary file somewhere (is should be https server, because Apple is limiting apps to secure limitation only)